# How can pass data from recyclerview to New Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

hi i want parse my data in to new activity .
I did this but it doesn't work properly and it doesn't transfer data
You can see my code below

my adapter
ItemViewAdapter.kt

```
    package com.example.app.adapter

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.app.R
import com.example.app.models.products.Results
import com.example.app.ui.home.DescriptionActivity
import java.security.AccessController.getContext

class ItemViewAdapter(private val context: Context) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemViewAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    private var itemList: MutableList<Results> = mutableListOf()
    private var page: Int = 0

    fun setListItem(item: List<Results>) {
        itemList.addAll(item)
        notifyItemRangeInserted(page * 10, (page.plus(1) * 10) - 1)
    }

    class MyViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

        private val title = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvTitle)
        private val code = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvNumber)
        private val quantity = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvQuantity)
        private val price = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvPrice)
        private val available = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvAvailable)
        private val category = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvCategory)

        fun bind(item: Results) {
            title.text = item.name
            code.text = item.code.toString()
            quantity.text = item.quantities[0].quantity.toString()
            price.text = item.prices[0].price.toString()
            available.text = item.active.toString()
            category.text = item.category?.name
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return itemList.size
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val data = itemList[position]
        holder.bind(data)
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(context, DescriptionActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("title", getItemId(position))
            intent.putExtra("code", getItemId(position))
            intent.putExtra("quantity", getItemId(position))
            intent.putExtra("price", getItemId(position))
            intent.putExtra("category", getItemId(position))
            intent.putExtra("info", getItemId(position))
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
    }
```

and my description activity

Description.kt

```
    package com.example.app.ui.home

import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Build
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.view.WindowInsetsController
import android.view.WindowManager
import com.example.app.R
import com.example.app.databinding.ActivityDescriptionBinding

@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
class DescriptionActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityDescriptionBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        window.apply {
            clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
            addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
            decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                    this@DescriptionActivity.window.decorView.windowInsetsController
                        ?.setSystemBarsAppearance(
                            0,
                            WindowInsetsController.APPEARANCE_LIGHT_STATUS_BARS
                        )
                }
            }
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityDescriptionBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)
        getItemIntent()

    }

    private fun getItemIntent(){
        val title = intent.getStringExtra("title")
        val code = intent.getStringExtra("code")
        val category = intent.getStringExtra("category")
        val info = intent.getStringExtra("info")
        val price = intent.getStringExtra("price")
        val quantity = intent.getStringExtra("quantity")

        setData(title,code,category,info,price,quantity)
    }

    private fun setData(title: String?, code: String?, category: String?, info: String?, price: String?, quantity: String?) {
        binding.tvTitle.setText(title)
        binding.tvCode.setText(code)
        binding.tvCategory.setText(category)
        binding.tvDescription.setText(info)
        binding.tvPrice.setText(price)
        binding.tvQuantity.setText(quantity)
    }
    }
```

But the data is not transferred.
If anyone can help me improve the code or offer me a sample code done with api so I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the data, you call `getItemId(position)` for every single line. This returns a `long`, not a string (and you put the same `long` for each attribute, which makes no sense)

```kotlin
intent.putExtra("title", getItemId(position))
intent.putExtra("code", getItemId(position))
```

but when you retrieve it, you look for a string

```kotlin
val title = intent.getStringExtra("title")
val code = intent.getStringExtra("code")
```

If you want to get a string, you need to put a string, probably like this (get the item for that row, then put its string attributes):

```kotlin
val data = itemList[position]
//...
intent.putExtra("title", data.name)
intent.putExtra("code", data.code.toString())
```

or if you want to get the text off the displayed views (have to make them non-private in the binding class):

```kotlin
intent.putExtra("title", binding.title.text.toString())
intent.putExtra("code", binding.code.text.toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass the entire object or most of its properties, you can add the library

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5' //Maybe the version is not the most recent, I just copied and pasted the implementation from the internet
```

And convert your object to a Json and pass it as a string

```
intent.putExtra("data", Gson().toJson(data))
```

and to receive it

```
val data = intent.getStringExtra("data", null)?.let { 
   Gson().fromJson(it, Results::Java.class)
}
```